# Moving an electolytic cap out of the way of a chip clip

Tags: capacitor, flash

I'm trying to read flash off an old sampler and I have all the required gear to do so.  However, there is an SMD electrolytic capacitor in the way keeping me from placing a TSOP 48 clip on the flash chip.

What I'm wondering is, after removing to allow me to put down the clip, how do I keep the cap in circuit and working?  I've attached a picture of the cap and also it in the circuit diagram (C75).  I'm also curious about the symbol used for this cap, can't say I've ever seen that before.

[image: cap blocking flash clip]
[image: circuit diagram]
[image: tsop blocked]

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a 100uF 6.3V cap. Probably polymer. Negative terminal on the black side. Measure the base and get a replacement. The size is standard. You can measure the capacitance to make sure once it is removed from the circuit. Could probably connect it to pads with short wire to get it out of the way since it is a bulk decoupling cap (i.e. low frequency) so a little extra wire inductance won't hurt.

Comment: Indeed, a through hole replacement would work well.  This is one case where I'd use an iron to desolder an SMD part, and avoid any heat concerns - in this case you actually can lift one side slightly after heating and then do the other.  Ultimately you will discover that this "SMD" part is really a through hole part sitting in a little high temperature plastic base.  If you don't need to preserve the original equipment and don't mind a little risk, you could even straighten the leads to pull off the plastic base and install it back on the pads canted off at an angle almost parallel the board.

Comment: Just don't get the polarity backwards!

Answer (score 1):

The Black polarity marker tells me it is an Alum Electrolytic and not a Polymer.

Possibly with low to  med ESR 0.25 Ohm < ESR < 5 Ohms for 100uF @ 6.3V. Thus Tau= ESR*C=25us to  which is pretty slow.

So relocating by adding path length at 5nH/cm (est) should not make it worse.  It lowers the resonant freq in the <1 MHz range, so the Q must be low any dynamic current must be low in the DAC to have low supply ripple.

Blue, Red , Purple polarity markers are used for Ultra-low ESR Polymer Alum e-caps 0.025 to 0.05 Ohms typ  for 100uF 6.4V

### Conclusion.

Moving cap by adding 1cm path length should not cause a functional issue, but if you experience non-linearity noise issues with a ramp output DACtest., adding a 0.1uF cap near the IC bottom side would be a better solution to permit the Chip Clip and supply transient currents with lower ESR.

Rework can use AWG30 magnet wire , plastic film insulation and instant adhesive to adhere part or equiv. Method. with Feedthrus on other side.

Comment: Oh, is that what the color represents on those marks? I never gave it much thought.